# How to add background shading to D3 line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I would like to add shading to the background of a D3 line graph. There would be different shades for different parts of the line. Here is an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqyah.jpg)

My approach is the add rectangle svg to the chart, but that doesn't seem to be working because I don't know how to make the width correspond with the data.

[here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aK6DP/33/)

Here is an example of the rectangle creation:

```
svg.append("rect")
   .attr("class", "shading")
   .attr("x", d[1].date)
   .attr("y", 80)
   .attr("width", 20)
   .attr("height", 20)
   .attr("fill", "blue");
```

Am I on the right track? How do I find the width so that it corresponds with the data?

**UPDATE:** There will be multiple square of different widths, so I can't just grab the width of the entire svg.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
 //get all the ticks in x axis
 //make a pair of it refer: d3.pair
 var data = d3.pairs(svg.selectAll(".x .tick").data());   
  //make a color category
 var c10 = d3.scale.category10();
 //to svg append rectangles
 svg.selectAll("rect")   
    .data(data)//for the tick pair
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
   .attr("class", "shading")
   .attr("x", function(d){return x(d[0])})//x will be the 1st tick
   .attr("y", 0)
   .attr("width", function(d){return (x(d[1]) - x(d[0]));})//width will be the diff of 1st and 2nd tick
   .attr("height", height)
     .attr("opacity", 0.2)
   .attr("fill", function(d,i){return c10(i)});//use color category to color the rects.
```

working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vmy37u67/)

Comment: Thank you! but I'm a little confused. How do I adjust it so that the squares can be any width, not just limited to the ticks? For example, your example, how if I want the shading to be differen twidths

Comment: I played with your example. Instead of using pairs I tried x(data[i]) to find the width.

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/vmy37u67/1/)

Comment: Hi, could you help me with this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66558856/how-to-use-scaletime-to-horizontally-position-a-background-rectangle

Answer (score 0):

fill the svg first with the data, then after that get the width property, it should automatically calculate it

Comment: There will be multiple square of different widths, so I can't just grab the width of the entire svg